# Spring MVC : webSocket or reactive Observable ?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket, rx-java

i want to make an asynchronous treatment after an HTTP call because this one can take several seconds. i want to inform the user that his treatment is in progress and notify him when it's done. For that i have first think to open an web socket and send a first message to notify user that treatment is in progress and a second when it is done.

But it is possible to do it with rxJava Observable ?

Thanks for help!